# I can't insert data one table to another table in room

Tags: android, database, android-studio, kotlin, android-room

Ín my app's room database I have a table called `movie_table`. When the user clicks the item, it is saved to another table called `favorite_table`. I tried almost two days but I can't solve it. I am new to MVVM.
For better understanding please see the code:

**FavoriteMovieDao.kt**

```kotlin
    
    @Dao
    interface FavoriteMovieDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertFavMovie(favorite: Favorite)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM favorite_table WHERE id LIKE :id")
    suspend fun getFavoriteMovieById(id:Int): Favorite

    @Query("SELECT * FROM favorite_table")
    suspend fun getAllFavoriteMovie(): List<Favorite>

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteFavorite(favorite: Favorite)
    }
```

**Repository.kt**

```kotlin
    class Repository(context: Context) {
        private val favoriteMovieDao: FavoriteMovieDao = MovieDatabase.invoke(context).getFavoriteMovieDao()
    suspend fun insertFavMovie(favorite: Favorite){
        favoriteMovieDao.insertFavMovie(favorite)
    }
```

**MovieDetailsViewModel.kt**

```kotlin
    class MovieDetailsViewModel(private val repository: Repository):ViewModel() {
        private val favMovieResponse:MutableLiveData<List<Favorite>> = MutableLiveData()
        val actorResponse:MutableLiveData<List<Movie>> = MutableLiveData()
        private val insertFavMovie:MutableLiveData<Favorite> = MutableLiveData()

        fun actorDetail(){
            viewModelScope.launch {
                val actor = repository.getAllMovieDB()
                actorResponse.value = actor
            }
        }

        fun insertFavMovie(favorite: Favorite){
            viewModelScope.launch {
                //i can't insert this
                val insertFav = repository.insertFavMovie(favorite)
                insertFavMovie.value = insertFav
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

**MovieDetailsActivity.kt**

```
class MovieDetailsActivity : AppCompatActivity(){

private lateinit var actorViewModel: MovieDeatilsViewModel
private val actorAdapter by lazy { ActorAdapter() }
private var isFav: Boolean = false


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_movie_details)


    val repository = Repository(this)
    val viewModelFactory = MovieDetailsViewModelFactory(repository)
    actorViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this,viewModelFactory).get(MovieDeatilsViewModel::class.java)

    setUpPostRecyclerView()
    actorViewModel.actorDetail()
    actorViewModel.actorResponse.observe(this, Observer {actorList ->
        actorAdapter.setData(actorList)
    })

    initBundle()
    
    favBtn.setOnClickListener {
        if (isFav){
            isFav = false
            favBtn.supportImageTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#E4C1C1"))

            Log.d("msg","Not Favorite!")
        }else{
            isFav = true
            favBtn.supportImageTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#FFC107"))
            Log.d("msg","Favorite!")
        }
    }

}

private fun initBundle() {
    val bundle:Bundle? = intent.extras
    movieTitle.text = bundle!!.getString("title")
    directorbc.text = bundle.getString("director")
    genre.text = bundle.getString("genre")
    releaseYear.text = bundle.getInt("year").toString()
    language.text = bundle.getString("language")
    country.text = bundle.getString("country")
    rating.text = bundle.getString("rating")
    plotText.text = bundle.getString("plot")
    //moviePosterD.setImageDrawable(bundle!!.getString("image"))
    Glide.with(this).load(bundle.getString("image")).into(moviePosterD);

    val player = SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).build()
    player.preparePlayer(movieView)
    player.setSource(applicationContext, "http://html5videoformatconverter.com/data/images/happyfit2.mp4")

}

private fun setUpPostRecyclerView(){
    actorRecyclerview.adapter = actorAdapter
    actorRecyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false)
}

}
```

How can I insert it? Please help me. Thank you

Comment: Can you please elaborate your `click` functionality implementation a bit more?

Comment: @theThapa i update my question, now you can see the click functionality.Thank you

Comment: Seems like you missed to call ViewModel's `fun insertFavMovie(favorite: Favorite){ .. }` function from within your `FAB` button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Movies table, to handle the favorite movies, you can make use of a variable in each movie item which you can for example set to true or false. This allows you to query using filters to show them on the screen. I don't think you need another table to store Favourites. I hope that helps! I can help you with the design if you share more details there.

```
@Entity
data class Movie( val title: String, val isFavourite: Boolean = false)
```

Update 1:

When user clicks on `favButton`, in `MovieViewModel` update the Movie entity like this:

```
fun setMovie(movie: Movie){
        _movie.value = movie
    }
fun updateMovie(movie: Movie) {
        movie.isFavourite = !movie.isFavourite
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.updateMovie(movie)
            setMovie(movie)
        }
    }
```

in `MovieDao`

```
@Update
suspend fun updateMovie(movie: Movie)
```

Update 2:
In `MoviesDao`

```
 @Update
    suspend fun updateMovie(movie: Movie)

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insertAll(vararg movie: Movie)

    @Query("select * from movies_table where isFavourite = 1")
    fun getFavMovies(): LiveData<List<Movie>>

    @Query("Select * from movies_table")
    fun getAllMovies(): LiveData<List<Movie>>
```

In Repository

```
val favMovies: LiveData<List<Movie>> = moviesDao.getFavMovies()
```

Update 3:

```
 favBtn.setOnClickListener {
            _viewModel.updateMovie(movie)
        }

_viewModel.movie.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            //Update UI based on isFavourite value on Movie
        })
```

Comment: I think your thought, I can generate an idea but can't implement it this time.I already sent you more details in your email. Please check your email and help me. Thank you

Comment: Which part exactly are you not able to understand? See, you have a Movies table, all the movies are stored in this, every Movie entity has a boolean value isFavourite which is set to false initially. When a movie is clicked to be added to favourites, isFavourite is set to true. You can retrieve all the movies or favouriteMovies by checking this variable, when you want to delete a movie from favourites, reset isFavourite to false again.

Comment: Thank you, i am creating this dao ` @Query("SELECT * FROM movie_table WHERE isFavorite LIKE :isFav")
    suspend fun getFavoriteMovie(isFav: Boolean)` is this correct?

Comment: Query would be    ` @Query("select * from movie_table where isFavourite = 1")  fun getFavouriteMovies(): LiveData<List<Movie>>`

Comment: ok,it's help me but i want to know user can click the favButton then it's select as a favorite movie.how can i do this.actually i want to know user can select their fav movie one by one then all fav movie show in a recyclerview.How can i do this?

Comment: I explain to you what i need, after your suggestion i remove favorite_table and add another variable isFavorite = false in Movie.kt class.then i create two method in dao class.1st one for click and second method for all favorite movie as list.here is my dao `//Favorite Query
    @Query("SELECT * FROM movie_table WHERE isFavorite = 1")
    suspend fun insertFavoriteMovie(isFav: Boolean):Boolean

    @Query("SELECT * FROM movie_table WHERE isFavorite = 1")
    fun getFavouriteMovies(): List<Movie>`

Comment: then create instance in repository class  `suspend fun getFavMovie(isFav:Boolean){
         movieDao.insertFavoriteMovie(isFav)
    }

    suspend fun getAllFavorite():List<Movie>{
        return movieDao.getFavouriteMovies()
    }`

Comment: but when i  observe this data in movieDetailsViewModel then it's show Type mismatch ` private val favMovieResponse:MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData()
    fun getFavMovie(isFavMovie:Boolean){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val fav = repository.getFavMovie(isFavMovie)
            favMovieResponse.value = fav  //type mismatch
        }
    }`

Comment: You don't have to pass isFavourite to get favourite movies. That is queried through isFavourite = 1. It returns list of all favourite movies not a Boolean value. Please check the above answer which I have updated.

Comment: i also update my question,i add the favButton. but what logic i put on this.

Comment: after update your answer it's looks like, in repository.kt `suspend fun getAllFavorite():List<Movie>{
        return movieDao.getFavouriteMovies()
    }`

Comment: in movieDetailsViewModel class `fun getFavMovie(){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val fav = repository.getAllFavorite()
            actorResponse.value = fav
        }
    }`

Comment: but how can i check favButton in your logic?